# Match the cart item amount and the order amount when calculating taxes

Tags: php, paypal

My problem is the following:

I have to include the "taxamt" parameter into my application to calculate the italian "iva", but when i do the order and i call the SetExpressCheckout the application send me back the generic message

Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.

The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

This is the input in the SetExpressCheckout.php

```
           $name = $L_NAME0;
       $itemamt = $L_AMT0;

       $PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT = 1.22; 

       $tax = $PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT;

       $amt = $L_AMT0*$tax;

       $nvpstr="";
       $nvpstr="&L_NAME0=".$name."&L_DESC0=".$L_DESC0."&L_AMT0=".$L_AMT0."&L_QTY0=".$L_QTY0."&TAXAMT=".$tax."&AMT=".(string)$amt."&ITEMAMT=".(string)$itemamt."&ReturnUrl=".$returnURL."&CANCELURL=".$cancelURL ."&CURRENCYCODE=".$currencyCodeType."&PAYMENTACTION=".$paymentType."&SOLUTIONTYPE=".$soleStr."&LANDINGPAGE=".$landingStr."&LOCALECODE=".$lang;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Short Message:  Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
Long Message:  The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.   I have updated the code to the current situation that makes me the error

Comment: What NVP version are you using?

Comment: Field `L_*` are deprecated from version 63.0. Go through the field on [this link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/#id09BHCI005L7) and check your code if it uses any other deprecated fields...

Comment: Do you think it could be a problem of this sort? I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried without the L_ prefix but nothing happens. I think, correct me, that the taxamt parameter is for adding fixed number taxes and you can't do a multiplication, so to use these taxes you can only add one to your account. is it possible like this? i can do only an addition

Comment: `TAXAMT` and `AMT` are deprecated since 63.0. I told you to check other fields if they are deprecated...

Comment: ok, i've checked them but i don't have found in this the solution to the enigma :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I have wrote before, where I said that `L_` fields are deprecated. I meant that field that you are using in your example/question, are deprecated, like field `L_NAME0`, `L_DESC0`, etc. And I have also given you **[link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/#id09BHCI005L7)**, where you see that `L_NAMEx` is replaced with `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAMEm`. I have never said, that you should remove `L_` prefix, and try that, that is just wrong!

Comment: If you had opened that link I have gave you, you would see sentence like: **`AMT` is deprecated since version 63.0. Use `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` instead.**

Comment: Or even better solution, why don't you just set NVP version to match your code?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Glavic, i've found that this was not the solution that i've been searching for and tax... was not what i wanted :)